# StateList Drawable not being implemented through Styles

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to change the `ImageButton` `src` attribute when it's states changes between `pressed` and `default` state (untouched). I created the below StateList Drawable named `ic_plus_states` -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_plus_white" android:state_pressed="true" />
<!--Default State-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_plus" />

</selector>
```

It works as intended when I set `android:src="@drawable/ic_plus_states"`
but when I use a style defined in `styles.xml` containing the exact same attribute, it doesn't works. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

I used this in my `styles.xml` -

```
<style name="ScoreButtons" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:tint">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_states</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PlusButtons" parent="ScoreButtons">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_plus_states</item>
        <item name="android:contentDescription">@string/plus_button</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I use a style defined in `styles.xml` containing the exact same
>   attribute, it doesn't works.

It's because of `android:tint` you have defined in style `ScoreButtons`.

If you Remove `android:tint` from `ScoreButtons`. You will get your output as expected.

```
<style name="ScoreButtons" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_states</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PlusButtons" parent="ScoreButtons">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_plus_states</item>
        <item name="android:contentDescription">@string/plus_button</item>
    </style>
```

> OR

You can set `android:tint="@null"` in style `PlusButtons`.

```
<style name="ScoreButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:tint">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PlusButton" parent="ScoreButton">
        <item name="android:tint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/state_change</item>
    </style>
```